# drawing box with latex

Tags: positioning, tcolorbox, box, frame

I want to write something like in the attached file.[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What did you try so far? My guess you can use `TikZ` and the library `background` to achieve this. Take a look at the manual for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess you are looking for something like this. You'll need to adapt the code to your requirements and graphics.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{luacolor} % LuaLatex needed to use this / replace with xcolor for PDFLatex

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,positioning,shadows,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[drop shadow,fill=white,rounded corners] (0,0) rectangle ++ (5,7) node(base) {};
        \node[align=center](quest) at (1.5,5) {\begin{tabular}{c l}
            Q   &   x = 6   \\
                &   y = 2   \\
                &   print(x**y) \\
                &   print(x/y)
        \end{tabular}};
        \draw[fill=blue] (2.5,7) circle[radius=0.6] node [white,align=center] {\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{example-image-b}};
    
        \begin{scope}[on background layer]
            \draw[drop shadow,fill=white,rounded corners,] ([xshift=-10mm,yshift=-10mm]base.north east) rectangle node[align=center] {\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image-a}}  ++ (3,2);
        \end{scope}
        
        \begin{scope}[block/.style={rectangle,rounded corners,drop shadow,fill=white,text width=20mm,align=left}]
            \node[block](ans) at (5.5,4.5)  {\textbf{A.} 66 0};
            \node[block,below=of ans,yshift=7.5mm] {\textbf{B.} 66 3};
            \node[block,below=of ans,yshift=0mm] {\textbf{C.} 36 0};
            \node[block,below=of ans,yshift=-7.5mm] {\textbf{D.} 36 3};
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: With pdflatex, this runs if you don't load **luacolor**. Great answer.

Comment: Yes .. under PDFLatex you need to load `xcolor` instead

Comment: thank you soo much

Comment: @alchemist No, color is managed directly by Tikz, no need to manually load **xcolor**.

Comment: I need a cup of coffee before answering  @quark67